# Laravel validation with comma in the value

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to use Laravel's "in" validation to validate data coming from a "select" input but some of the options in the select might contain comma which is a special character in validation string. Is there a way to escape commas.
Eg:
if the select has "foo", "bar" and "foo, bar" as option the following Laravel validation doesn't work:
"field" => "in:foo,bar,foo, bar"

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Rule` facade instead:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'field' => [
        Rule::in(['foo', 'bar', 'foo, bar']),
    ],
]);
```

More validation logic can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation).

Comment: This won't work for Laravel 5.4 or lower. In Laravel 5.4 you have to use the double quote character to escape the special characters, e.g. `'field' => 'in:foo,bar,"foo,bar"'` (or `Rule::in(['foo', 'bar', '"foo,bar"'])`). More details can be found in source by comparing [v5.5](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/In.php#L37) and [v5.4](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/In.php#L37). To escape the " symbol use "" (`'test' => 'required|in:foo,bar,"foo,bar","foo""bar"'`).